# Playing a random animation after some time without input

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

So here's what I'd like to do: The player is idling on the ground, not moving at all. And after some time a random idle animation should be played. How do I detect that the player hasn't been moving for a certain amount of time?

```
IEnumerator Idle()
{
    // check if player is idling on the ground
    if (grounded && (_controller.velocity.x == 0))
    {
        // Now what?
        //...
    }
    idleIndex = IdleRandom();
    _animator.SetInteger("IdleIndex", idleIndex);
    _animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}

int IdleRandom()
{
    // choose random index of idle animations
    int i = Random.Range(0, numberOfIdleAnims);

    // if it's the same as the previous one...
    if (i == idleIndex) {
        // try another one
        return IdleRandom ();
    }
    else
        return i;
}
```

I've already set up my animator controller so that it would play one of the idle animations (chosen by the idleIndex) if the idle-Trigger is pushed. The only thing I cannot figure out is the not-moving-in-certain-time thing!

Comment: Can you show me where you call `Idle()`?

Comment: Nowhere yet! But I will try out the answer by FunctionR and will update then!

Comment: If you show me how you call your `Idle()` function I can improve my answer more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the time your player has been idle, not moving. You can do this in the `void FixedUpdate()` function.

I have drastically changed my code. Make sure you include the code for playing animations.

```
public class IdleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private isIdle = false;
    private float previousTime;
    private const float IDLE_TIME = 5.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        if(!isIdle && grounded && (_controller.velocity.x == 0))
        {
            isIdle = true;
            previousTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad();
        }

        else if(isIdle && Time.timeSinceLevelLoad - previousTime > IDLE_TIME)
        {
            // Play animation here.

            // Reset previousTime.
            previousTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;  
        }

        else if(grounded || _controller.velocity.x > 0)
            isIdle = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only simply do the same count in your coroutine.

Comment: @Marconius    It depends on how he calls `Idle()`. That's why I want him to post that call.

Comment: *she :) ; anyways, I haven't called it anywhere yet, because I didn't know where I should call it. But I guess I would call it anytime the game "notices" that the player is idling (thus grounded && velocity.x == 0)

Comment: It's giving me an error of "`PlayerControl_new.Idle()': not all code paths return a value", what does the IEnumerator need to return?

Comment: @hollowspecter You don't really need an IEnumerator. Use the new code I just posted above, it will do what you want.